# Form element's #required set to FALSE, but form submission still consider it as required

Tags: forms

I am trying to theme Contact form with template file, manipulating the contact form with form API, trying to hide the subject field and make it optional for submission.

```
$form['subject']['#required'] = FALSE;
hide($form['subject']);
```

I used `dsm()` to confirm that the `#required` is successfully set to `FALSE`.

[image: screenshot]

However, when I submit the form, it still ask me to fill in Subject field. (The cache has been cleared.)

[image]

These are the steps that I have followed:

- In the template.php file I added the following code

  ```
  function mytheme_theme() {
    return array(
      'contact_site_form' => array(
        'render element' => 'form',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/templates',
        'template' => 'contact-site-form',
      ),
   );
  ```
- I created the contact-site-form.tpl.php file with the following code

  ```
  $form['subject']['#required'] = FALSE;
  hide($form['subject']);
  print drupal_render_children($form);
  ```
- I cleared the cache

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, theming the form only changes its markup. If you want to change the form you have to hook_form_alter.

I once wondered how to add required styles to elements that weren't actually required. Your question just gave me the answer.

Comment: ... and in your hook_form_alter function, don't forget to pass $form as reference (e.g hook_form_alter(&$form)) {}

Answer (score 4):

I see that its an old post but still...
try to use this via `hook_alter()`

```
$form['subject'][und]['#required'] = FALSE;
```

well worked in my case:

```
$form['field_client']['und']['#required'] = FALSE;
hide($form['field_client']);
```

interesting that for 'title' field its just:

```
$form['title']['#required'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why your form field is still failing on validation, but try `$form['subject']['#access'] = FALSE;` to achieve what you want.

Comment: $form['subject']['#access'] = FALSE;                      doesn't work. "Subject field is required" still.

Comment: Hmm, what version of Drupal? If you give me the whole hook I can try/play with it on a test system.

Comment: Drupal 7. Then enable the contact form.  Go to /contact.  See if you can make the subject field optional with FORM API?

Comment: I have updated the questions, upload the screenshot of code and the steps. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I got it. I Should use hook_form_alter. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't realise you were doing that in the the theme. I'd assumed you were working in a module with hook_form_alter. Good get :)

Comment: You may need `$form[$key]['widget']['#access']` instead.

Answer (score 2):

In drupal 8

`$form['field_first_name']['#access'] = FALSE;
$form['field_last_name']['#access'] = FALSE;
$form['field_gender']['#access'] = FALSE;`

works fine for me.