# How can I specify required fields when programmatically loading a node creation form?

Tags: 7, forms

I'm building out a custom workflow. Newly registered users can create a node that has several fields - some of the fields are required, others are pre-filled, and others are disabled. The benefits for having 1 content type to handle this greatly outweigh the negatives.

Fields that I set the `#default_value`, `#access`, or any other FAPI attribute on are working properly, but fields where I set #required = TRUE are **not** validating and are **not** stopping the node from being created!

Here's my code:

```
function my_custom_callback($arg) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
  $page['node_form'] = node_add('content_type_name');

  if ($arg == 'foo') {
    $page['node_form']['field_favorite_color'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#required'] = TRUE;
  } else if ($arg == 'bar') {
    $page['node_form']['field_favorite_food'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#required'] = TRUE;
  }
}
```

If I visit this page with `$arg = 'foo'`,  I can submit this form without entering anything in `field_favorite_color`, even though this field shows the red asterisk and has the class 'required' and is showing as `#required = TRUE` in the form's render array when I do a `dpm()` within the callback function.

Why won't Drupal require that this required fields be filled out? Do I need to rebuild the form somehow after I've altered the fields? If I set the same code in a `hook_form_alter()` then it works as expected, but in that case I don't have the control that I get through my custom callback to lead the user through a multi-step workflow.

**Edit:** This is Drupal 7. Tried adding that tag but am seeing 'drupal-7' and 'drupal7' tags are not allowed.

Comment: Reading this answer http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/17027/3586 makes me think I'm just affecting the theming layer, however my default values are still working even as the required attributes are not.

Comment: I can't tell much without more code. And I don't understand why you are creating a custom callback in the first place. Why not just form_alter the node form? You can play with session variables, DB variables or just URL args to get a multi-step workflow if need be.

Answer (score 3):

In short, to answer your question "*How can I specify required fields when programmatically loading a node creation form?*" ... use hook_form_alter() and keep your sanity! :)

Here is what I ended up doing after toying with a bunch of proposed solutions I ran across wile learning hook_form_alter() and Drupal's [Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7).

I'm sure this solution could be massively improved, but this worked for me and it seems to be fairly simple to manage/maintain.

**Managing a Single Content Type With a Complex Workflow Using Node Edit Forms**

First after hours of debugging, I decided not to use a custom callback.  Instead I edited the built in node add/edit form using nothing more than [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)(). (I like [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)() instead of hook_form_alter() as it helps me keep my code organized. A personal preference for sure.)

> Note: Drupal 7 use the Administration theme by default for creating
>   new nodes/content. You can get around this by unchecking the '***[Use
>   the administration theme when editing or creating content](http://www.drupalgardens.com/documentation/site-management/admin-theme)***'
>   field at the bottom of 'admin/appearance' page in the admin panel.

**Using the Rules Module To Keep Track Of Workflow Stages**

I added a new field called "workflow" to my node type (Added through UI at: http://example.com/admin/structure/types/manage/%content_type%/fields) so I could keep track of what stage the user was currently at.

My workflow field ($form['field_workflow']) was a select list with predefined options (stages).

```
 'new' => 'New', //Default Value For New Nodes
 'foo' => 'Foo',
 'bar' => 'Bar'
```

I used the [Rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules) to move the workflow along.  [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) allowed me to move a bunch of the '[submit function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#submit_property)' code into rules configuration.  This made updates simpler as I don't need to make as many module edits.

[Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) makes it very simple to do things like 'if the node is new, set the workflow to *foo* after saving' or 'if the workflow is set to *foo*, set the new workflow state to *bar* after saving.'

**Organization: Ugh...  Setting Up The Actual Flow**

First I tried to keep each stage of the workflow as clean as possible by packing alterations in their own functions with a custom naming convention.

```
function MODULE_stage_new(&$form) {
    //Insert all alterations here for use when node has not yet been saved. It's new!
    $form['field_favorite_color'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#access'] = FALSE;
    $form['field_favorite_food'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#access'] = FALSE;
}

function MODULE_stage_foo(&$form) {
    //Insert all 'foo' stage alterations here.
    $form['field_favorite_color'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#required'] = TRUE;
}

function MODULE_stage_bar(&$form) {
    //Insert all 'bar' stage alterations here.
    $form['field_favorite_food'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#required'] = TRUE;
}

/**
* Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
*/
function MODULE_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
    /**
    * Place any alterations here that apply to all stages here before the 
    * 'if' statements below.
    *
    * I generally place my validation callbacks and CSS additions here.
    **/

    if (empty($form['nid']['#value'])) {
        MODULE_stage_new($form);
    } else if ($arg == 'foo') {
        MODULE_stage_foo($form);
    } else if ($arg == 'bar') {
        MODULE_stage_bar($form);
    }
}
```

Now that hook_form_alater() is being used exclusively without a custom callback, you shouldn't have any issues with the `['#required']` elements.

Occasionally I would have to add an '#after_build' function (yea, yet another function to keep track of...) but did so with a common naming convetion.  For example, if I needed to add a new stylesheet at the 'foo' stage I would use the following functions.

```
function MODULE_stage_foo(&$form) {
    //Insert all 'foo' stage alterations here.
    $form['field_favorite_color'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#required'] = TRUE;
    $form['#after_build'][] = 'MODULE_stage_foo_after_build';
}

function MODULE_stage_foo_after_build($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . "/css/foo.css");
    return $form;
}
```

I hope this wasn't too overkill or off topic.  I honestly found that sticking to hook_form_alter() for node add/edit form modifications saved me a ton of headaches over how I was trying to do it before.  The custom callback method using `module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');` never worked for me the way it seemed to for [people writing the examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344754/drupal-7-how-to-display-node-add-sometype-form-on-another-page) I found.  Then again, I'm still pretty new to Drupal. :)

Answer (score 0):

One answer **(that I really hope is not the correct one!)** to this is to have my custom callback remain in charge of the node creation form's appearance:

```
function my_custom_callback($arg) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
  $page['node_form'] = node_add('content_type_name');

  if ($arg == 'foo') {
    // do something informative to the user.
  } else if ($arg == 'bar') {
    // do another thing informative to the user.
  }
}
```

and then set my requirements and general form alterations in `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`, but this means I'm spreading my code out in 2 places **and** I've got to look in the `arg()` function to see what the user's workflow state is, which is generally messy.

Comment: You can set a global flag instead of relying on arg(). But yes, that is your only choice, you can not alter the form after it has been returned from drupal_get_form() because validation happens based on the cached form data and that does not include your changes.

Comment: Argh! I've tried every combo of drupal_rebuild_form(), drupal_build/prepare_form(), etc., but I just can't get any of my new stuff to take effect. Can you point me in the direction of why the FAPI works this way? Why can't I just clear the cached form data and rebuild it?

Comment: Implementing hook_form_alter() to change form structure is the correct way to do it, no matter how 'messy' it may seem to you. And you don't need to check `arg()` in your callback function, since it's already checked and correct settings are set in your `hook_form_alter` no? All your callback needs to do is call `node_add` and return the page elements, and let `hook_form_alter` do the altering. So you don't even need callback function then, you just specify `node_add` as `'page calback'` in `hook_menu` and `'content_type'` as `'page argument'`. Then you only need hook_menu and hook_form_alter